# Installed Font, but can't use it in any application, it previews but can't be used

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, adobe-illustrator

https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/tree/master/fonts
I tried the ttf.

It's a bunch of metro icons/glyphs. Installs fine in OSX or Windows and
neither detect any problems with it. I can preview it and select it in
applications like illustrator, but as soon as I select it and start typing, nothing
happens and it switches back to some other font.

Can someone please see what's up with it and how can I use it. I really need some icons from there. I also tried pressing different keys, caps lock on/off etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a font expert, but from what I could gather the symbols in that font are part of the  [Unicode Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29) (U+E000–U+F000), as shown by Character Map:

[image: 1]

As such I too was unable to simply type letters of the alphabet using the font, and attempting to do so switched the font automatically to one that did support the letters I was typing.

What I was able to do was copy characters using Character Map and paste into Word, or use `Insert / Symbol` in Word to insert the characters I wanted from that font.